# g++ assembly generation(order of variables)

Tags: assembly, g++

Two versions of simple C code :

```
int main(){

    int array[4];
    int i=0;
    array[4]=0;
}
```

and

```
int main(){
    int i=0;
    int array[4];

    array[4]=0;
}
```

i compiled with g++ like this: g++ -x c -S -masm=intel -fverbose-asm -l -c test.c

In BOTH version i got same assmebly code:

```
_main:
LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    push    ebp  #
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    mov ebp, esp     #,
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    and esp, -16     #,
    sub esp, 32  #,
    call    ___main  #
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+28], 0    # i,
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+28], 0    # array,
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE0:
```

Can someone explain why? I mean shouldn't order of i and array be different ?
Many thanks for help.

Comment: Why do you think it should be different?

Comment: order of i and array? it was changed ,but not in assembly.

Comment: Since the program has undefined behaviour, absolutely *any* machine code would constitute a correct implementation of the program.

Comment: +1 @KerrekSB, and even if it *were* well defined, the compiler is still free to order local variables however it wants to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *why* to be had.  The compiler can order local variables however it wants to.  The order in which you declared them has nothing to do with anything.